# How to make link in background image in html

Tags: html, css

I want to other link to background image`(/var/www/html/new/bannerfooter.jpg)`

Code below.

```
<tr>
   <td align="center" style="background:url(/var/www/html/new/bannerfooter.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; height:160px;padding-left:140px;">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <!--image link here--> style="padding-top:70px"/>
      </a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <!--image link here-->
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: why you don't want to do that. You can link that div which has that image as a bg

Comment: As a side note: You cannot use an absolute path for linking an image. You must use an URL such as background: `url('new/bannerfooter.jpg')` (relative) or `url('http://www.example.org/new/bannerfooter.jpg')` (absolute).

Answer (score 1):

You can just insert an `img` element inside the `a` tag

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
</a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gN8bL/)

Answer (score 0):

try style="background-image:url('/var/www/html/new/bannerfooter.jpg')" in your tag. Make sure the path "/var/www/html/new/bannerfooter.jpg" is also right.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td align="center" style="background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg     ) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; height:160px;padding-left:140px;">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" style="height:20px; width:100px; display:block;"/>
   "text"

  </a>

 </td>
</tr></table>
```

If you don't need any text between a tag then remove text from a tag. You can set position of a tag as you want..